# Bind to property on first element in SwiftData @Query array

Tags: swiftui, binding, swift-data

I have a SwiftData model `Player` and there should only ever be 0 or 1 in the database. When the user is on the Main Menu and taps to Start a New Game, I walk them through a couple of screens to pick the options for the game. Once all of the options are chosen, I delete all existing `Player` objects and insert a new one. Then I dismiss all of those options picking screens.

Then what I want to happen is to automatically show the game view. But I'm not sure how to bind my `.fullScreenCover()` to the `Player.isShown` property on the first element in my SwiftData `@Query`.

The code below doesn't work because: `Cannot convert value of type 'Bool?' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'`

I'm still very new to Swift and SwiftUI, so my grasp on bindables and observables is still tenuous.

```
struct RootContentView: View {
    @Query var activeplayers: [Player] // should only ever be 0 or 1

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // stuff            
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: activeplayers.first?.isshown content: {
                GameView()
        })
        
    }
    
}
```

How can I automatically show my `GameView` screen based on the optional first element in my SwiftData `@Query`?

---

I also tried just querying to see if any players exist with `.isShown == true` and then binding to `$activeplayers.isEmpty` (this is the reverse of the logic I actually want, but I was just trying to find SOME way to distill the data down to a single bool property and I figured I could work on reversing the logic later) but that didn't work either:

```
@Query (filter: #Predicate<Player> {
        $0.isshown == true
    }) var activeplayers: [Player]

// ...

// without the $, gives the error: 
// Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: activeplayers.isEmpty content: {
        GameView()
})

// with the $, gives the error:
// Cannot find '$activeplayers' in scope
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $activeplayers.isEmpty content: {
        GameView()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this simple approach, using an extra `@State var shouldShow`
and setting it in `.onAppear {...}` as shown in the example code

```
struct RootContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query var activeplayers: [Player]
    
    @State var shouldShow = false // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("testing")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shouldShow) {  // <-- here
            GameView()
        }
        // -- here
        .onAppear {
            if let player = activeplayers.first, let doShow = player.isshown {
                shouldShow = doShow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Neat. So much to learn about SwiftUI. This seems like a good solution in general. In my specific case, it didn't work out because `onAppear` doesn't get called when the subsequent screens are dismissed (because of the pageSheet presentation). But the sheet() action allows me to add a dismiss handler and then I can put your suggested solution into that. My code above shows fullScreenCover() instead of sheet(), so I accepted your solution. The original code design was using sheet() but I had experimented with fullScreenCover() to see if I could get things working and forgot to change above.